# LWJGL Key Event State not working

Tags: java, keyboard, lwjgl

LWJGL seems to be bugging out on me (or I am being a dunce again).  I am using the following code:

```
if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_Q) {
    if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
        System.err.println("Pressed");
    }else {
        System.err.println("Released");
    }
}
```

When I press and release 'Q', it prints out neither "Pressed" nor "Released". Help?

EDIT: Problem solved. You first must poll the Keyboard buffer before using getEventKey(). Fixed code is:

```
while(Keyboard.next()) {
        if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_Q) {
            System.out.println("HI");
            if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
                System.out.println("Pressed");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Released");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `System.out.println()`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  It just prints the text red so I can see it inbetween all the other print outs I have.  Even if I change it, it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per API:

> public static int getEventKey()
>
> **Please note that the key code returned is NOT valid against the current keyboard layout**. To get the actual character pressed call getEventCharacter
>
> Returns: The key from the current event

Try changing your first `if` statement to use `getEventCharacter` menthod as:

```
   if(Keyboard.getEventCharacter() == Keyboard.KEY_Q) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in my programs... I make a boolean for the character and then run a method in the game loop to check it:

```
public static boolean keyboardA;

public static void refresh() {
keyboardA = Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A);
}

public static void game_loop() {
refresh();
}
```

If you need me to explain more just comment :P
Hope it helps